# JSP to Excel encoding problem. Value=?

Tags: excel, jsp, encoding

Jsp page shows arabic character verywell as like this:

> about something       bla bla       تضارب توقعات شهر أكتوبر فيق الـ و الـ

but when I export it to Excel and try to open it,Excel says:

> The file you are trying to open 'example.xls' is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

After clicking yes, value is which I wrote before is:

> about something       bla bla       ??????????????????????????

Jsp page has:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" import="java.util.*" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

if I copy arabic characters and paste it to Excel,Excel shows them clearly.

I use    charset=cp1254.
when I change it to charset=cp1256, Value is like freak characters.

any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're fooling Excel by a plain vanilla HTML file with the wrong extension. This is not going to work flawlessly, as Excel has warned you.

You need to serve a real binary XLS file using a Servlet, not some HTML table using a JSP. You can use [Apache POI HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/) or [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Comment: actually I've got non-English characters in Excel with opening xls from DATA/FromText. Because Excel shows me a selection charset window and i choosed utf-8,it looks great. The problem is double-clicking xls file do not shows me a selection charset. have an idea?

Comment: Make it a real XLS file instead of a HTML file with the wrong extension.

Comment: there are lots of jsp pages that I am exporting to Excel,How am I gonna create xls file for each? is there a misunderstanding?

Comment: That can be done with a single servlet. You're now just victim of a major design mistake from the beginning on.